# why this loop is running so slowly: c#

Tags: c#, performance, list, loops

So am working on a text mining project and currently trying to implement info gain. I have a data in which each line depict a document. so a new line character splits different documents.

i have to generate a matrix in which columns are all the distinct words in all documents and rows are different document. each cell in this table is either 1(true) or 0(false) for if the word is present or not in that document.
there are 987 documents, total words are 22860 and total distinct words are 3680. so 3680 words are compared with 22860. this is running slow but am fine with it. The loop that is taking more time is when i traverse through the objects of list of words to generate matrix. see below

Note: i have removed all repeated words in a document already.

```
 class word_list
        {
            public string word;
            public List<bool> doc= new List<bool>();
        };//class ends

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert the string into an array of words 
            string[] w1 = richTextBox1.Text.Trim().Split('\n',' ').Select(x => x.Trim().ToLower()).Distinct().ToArray(); //all distinct words
            string[] rich_doc = richTextBox1.Text.Trim().Split('\n'); //all documents array
            List<word_list> words = new List<word_list>();

            richTextBox2.Text+=("no. of distict words: " + w1.Length + ", no. of docs " + rich_doc.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < w1.Length; i++)
            {
                word_list temp = new word_list();
                temp.word = w1[i]; //temp has the current distict word as class object

                for(int j=0;j<rich_doc.Length;j++)//traverse all doc array
                {
                    temp.doc.Add(false);
                    List<string> doc_word = Regex.Split(rich_doc[j], @"\b").Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
                    //richTextBox2.Text += ("\n no. of words in this doc: " + doc_word.Count);
                    //richTextBox2.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                    //richTextBox2.Focus();
                    int doc_count = doc_word.Count; // number of docs
                    for (int k = 0; k < doc_count; k++)//All words in a doc are compared
                    {
                        if(doc_word[k].ToLower() == w1[i].ToLower())
                        {
                            temp.doc[temp.doc.Count-1]=true;                            
                            break;
                        }
                    }                      
                }
                if ((words.Count - 1)>=0)
                    richTextBox2.Text += ("\n word(" + words.Count + "/" + w1.Length + "): " + words[words.Count - 1].word);
                richTextBox2.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox2.Focus();
                words.Add(temp);
            }
            //generate matrix
            int t = rich_doc.Length; //no. of docs
            int word_count = words.Count;
            richTextBox1.Text = "Doc";
            foreach (word_list w in words)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += "\t" + w.word;
            }
            richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
//This loop is slow
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) //traverse through number of docs
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += i + 1;
                for (int h = 0; h < word_count; h++)//traverse through each distinct word in the list
                {
                    if (words[h].doc[i])
                        richTextBox1.Text += "\t1";
                    else
                        richTextBox1.Text += "\t0";
                }
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
            }
        }//end of button 2
```

Comment: mediafire.com/?4mojnj4j153q76s : this is the data am working on and richtextbox2 is for testing purpose

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to build the strings instead of using `TextBox.Text` as a working space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ta.speot.is is correct. Strings are supposed to be built with [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), using [`Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8.aspx) for instance, and only after the loop you assign the string to `richTextBox1.Text`. The code would look like this:

```
        //generate matrix
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int t = rich_doc.Length; //no. of docs
        int word_count = words.Count;
        richTextBox1.Text = "Doc";
        foreach (word_list w in words)
        {
            sb.Append("\t");
            sb.Append(w.word);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();

        //This loop is not slow anymore :)
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) //traverse through number of docs
        {
            sb.Append(i + 1);
            for (int h = 0; h < word_count; h++)//traverse through each distinct word in the list
            {
                if (words[h].doc[i])
                    sb.Append("\t1");
                else
                    sb.Append("\t0");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

EDIT: There are valuable comments below. Changing [RichEditBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx) property is the most expensive operation here.

Comment: Would give it try now

Comment: The `StringBuilder` is likely a trivial optimization compared to not using the `richTextBox1.Text`. Setting `Text` will kick of a whole variety of processing.

Comment: The fact that he uses `string+=` is probably not as much pain as the fact that he uses `richTextBox.Text+=` ;) Of course string-addition is much slower than StringBuilder.Append, but setting the text and relaying/redrawing the text on the screen is even slower! (although RTBox probably does not repaint immediatelly, but still it forces invalidate and many unnecessary repaints.)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yes, I have noted as much.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - yep I've seen you beat me by 10 seconds:) but actually I  wanted to hint Dialecticus to include the actual problem in his answer.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl previously i was using a different string to append but that was also too slow. the program is working for 4-5 lines i have checked but when try it for 987 documents. the program ran overnight and still was running to have me stop it my self. it wa testing purpose that i used richtextbox.text

Comment: @ta.speot.is thanks. the results are extremely fast now. program took less than few minutes to complete.